# How to group data in sql without aggregate funcation

Tags: sql, group-by

here is my table data and i want to group the data with respect to the SpecificationParameter.

[image]

Comment: Your table data is missing.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @HiSura table data image is added

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name table data image added

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be more specific. What do you mean "group the data"?  The best way to explain is to give a few sample rows of the resultset you need.

Comment: Please read this guide on [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your question with example data and desired results *(which, as mentioned, should be formatted text and not links to images)*

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to properly group this without excluding the subtype column.
With that in mind I would do Select id, distict SpecificationParameter, lookuptypename from x

Answer (score 0):

```
select Distinct Id,SpecificationParameter,LookUpTypeName From yourTableName
```